# Python Django embedding static tags inside strings

Tags: python, django, string, url, tags

Want to generate a dynamic HTML code as python string with some embedded images as shown in the following django code. This code is supposed to be added to another existing HTML file with **load static header**.

```
def printFollowups(self):
        return """
            <table>
            <tr>
            <td>
            <p><strong> Hello World </strong></p>
            </td>
            <td>
            <img src="{% static 'images/logo.png' %}" align="right">
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>"""
```

But, the problem is that image is not rendered on a page. May be problem with the quotes. Want to know how to embed django static tags inside the python string.

Tried with different quotes and concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a Python string, you can use Django templates or the `render_to_string("path/to/template.html", context)` function from `django.template.loader`, depending on how you are adding the code to an existing HTML file.  If you are updating the page dynamically with an Ajax call for example, then `render_to_string()` is a potential solution, otherwise just include the template with `{% include 'path/to/template.html' %}` and add context variables in the view rendering the parent.

Example Template File

```
{% load static %}
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p><strong> Hello World </strong></p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="{% static CONTEXT_VARIABLE_WITH_PATH %}" align="right">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and just make sure the `CONTEXT_VARIABLE_WITH_PATH` is available in the view or `render_to_string` context.